# How to set map View and List View to can't touchable when the front panel is showing

Tags: android, listview, panel, android-mapview

How to set map View and List View to can't touchable when the front panel is showing

I have map view , list view and panel.
all I want is when I open panel , mapview and list view will show be hide the panel and can't touch on map view and list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the mapView.setClickable(false). This should prevent the map interacting to touches.